# Can functions be called without a class? php

Tags: php, function, class

Can functions be called without a class outside of a class?

I have some code that I found to do hashing and authentication for my passwords. The php file however doesn't have a class declaration at the top just the functions.  I'm not sure how to call the functions from my other pages. [Here is the hashing file I'm using](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#phpsourcecode)

The Hashing file is set up like this :

```
<?php    

public function MyFunction() {
}
```

Rather than like this:

```
<?php

class MyClass{

    public function MyFunction() {
    }
}
```

I have tried 
    include_once 'PasswordHash.php';

Then in my page calling the functions with these:

```
Echo PasswordHash::create_hash('$Pass');
Echo create_hash('$Pass');
Echo PasswordHash->create_hash('$Pass');
```

None of them work and show Fatal error:blah blah cant find class.

Thank you for reading and your help.

Comment: I completely don't understand what you try to do. What is public function MyFunction not inside class?

Comment: That is what I'm trying to figure out.
why the code doesn't have a class declaration, so I'm wondering why they did that. if so how does it work without a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to initiate your classes.

```
$password = new PasswordHash($pass);
echo $password->create_hash;
```

Or something along those lines.

Comment: Is that the best way to make it work, to make an object then call it?
   require_once'../Login/PasswordHash.php';
            
            $password = new PasswordHash('$pass');
            echo $password->create_hash;
Shows this error
    Fatal error: Class 'PasswordHash' not found in

Comment: You will need to read and understand the documentation given for the classes/functions you provided. All of the docs are in the link you provided. Please read them first and you are still having trouble come back and ask again.

Comment: Will do ,thank you. 
I just noticed that the page linked to other files showing how to use it. I feel a little dumb now

Answer (score 1):

Several issues:

- `create_hash('$pass')` will create a hash of the string `$pass`, not the value of the variable, pass like this: `create_hash($pass)`
- You must create an instance of your class, before you can call its methods.
- You linked to a non-OO code example, why bother using classes, instead of using the code that is already there?

So, if you are going to continue using this class:

```
$hasher = new MyClass();//or whatever name you gave the class
echo 'The hash of the password is: ', $hasher->createHash($pass);//<-- change createHash with correct method name
```

If you are going to copy paste the example code (if it's allowed), simply call it like any old function:

```
echo 'The hash of the password is: ', create_hash($pass);
```

But make sure the functions are declared:

```
if (!function_exists('create_hash'))
    include 'path/to/file/containing/create_hash_functions.php';
```

Oh, and functions outside a class don't have access modifiers:

```
function thisWorks(){}
//note: no public
public function thisFails(){}// <== error!
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that you must create the object then you can work with it.
no need to make it a class just the functions.

```
include_once '../Resources/PasswordHash.php';    

   $result = validate_password("foobar", $hash);
```

That was all it needed.
Just to be included and then you can call it like any other function in the class.